# No Overload matches delegate 'Action' when selecting method via an expression

Tags: c#, .net, generics, linq-expressions

I am trying to create a fluent API that allows selecting class methods. When attempting to select a method with a parameter, I am getting the error:

`No overload for 'MethodB' matches delegate 'Action'`.

It seems like C# isn't automatically determining the right generic method. If I specify the generic type in the call signature, it works, but if omitted, it doesn't. Normally, if I were using this technique to select properties or fields, the generic type would be determined automatically, but I suspect C# (or Visual Studio) is not able to auto-determine the type because it is wrapped inside of an `Action<>`.

**Is there a way I can ensure that calls to this method will not require an explicit generic type to be stated?** If not, I am curious to know why.

```
public class Program
{

  public static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    var builder = new OperationBuilder<SomeClass>();
    builder.AddMethod( x => x.MethodA );
    builder.AddMethod( x => x.MethodB ); // Gives error
    builder.AddMethod<double>( x => x.MethodB ); // Works correctly
  }


  public class OperationBuilder<T>
    where T : class
  {
    private List<MethodInfo> methods;

    public OperationBuilder()
    {
      methods = new List<MethodInfo>();
    }

    public OperationBuilder<T> AddMethod( MethodInfo method )
    {
      methods.Add( method );
      return this;
    }

    public OperationBuilder<T> AddMethod( Expression<Func<T, Action>> expression )
      => AddMethod( expression.GetMethodInfo() );

    public OperationBuilder<T> AddMethod<T1>( Expression<Func<T, Action<T1>>> expression )
      => AddMethod( expression.GetMethodInfo() );

  }

  public class SomeClass
  {

    public void MethodA()
    {
    }

    public void MethodB( double value )
    {
    }

  }

}

public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
  public static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<TClass>(
    this Expression<Func<TClass, Action>> expression )
    => GetMethodInfoInternal( expression );

  public static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<TClass, T1>(
    this Expression<Func<TClass, Action<T1>>> expression )
    => GetMethodInfoInternal( expression );

  private static MethodInfo GetMethodInfoInternal( LambdaExpression expression )
  {
    if( !( expression.Body is UnaryExpression unary ) )
      throw new ArgumentException(
        "Expression is not unary.",
        nameof( expression ) );

    if( !( unary.Operand is MethodCallExpression methodCall ) )
      throw new ArgumentException(
        "Expression is not a method call.",
        nameof( expression ) );

    if( !( methodCall.Object is ConstantExpression constant )
      || !( constant.Value is MethodInfo methodInfo ) )
      throw new ArgumentException(
        "Expression does not contain a valid method reference.",
        nameof( expression ) );

    return methodInfo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `x.MethodB` you are actually not directly providing a delegate, but rather a so-called [method group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#expression-classifications). Method groups can be [implicitly converted to a **given** compatible delegate type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#anonymous-function-conversions).

Thus, the compiler faces the following situation when trying to infer the generic type argument `T1` of your `AddMethod<T1>` method. To be able to infer `T1`, the compiler would need to know the concrete `Action<T1>` delegate type at hand. But all the compiler is given is a method group, not a `Action<double>` delegate.

To be able to (implicitly) convert the method group to a delegate, the compiler would need to know a compatible delegate type the method group should be converted to. But the compiler would only be able to know this delegate type if it could infer `T1`, which again would require it to know the concrete `Action<T1>` type. Catch-22.

A similar but simpler problem that is illustrating the same underlying issue:

```
static void SomeMethod<T1>(Action<T1> action) { }

var sc = new SomeClass();
SomeMethod(sc.MethodB); // compile error, type argument cannot be inferred
```

Here, too, the compiler will be unable to infer *SomeMethod's* type parameter `T1` because it is given a method group and not an `Action<T1>` delegate. And it can't succeed in converting the method group into a delegate because to determine the actual concrete `Action<T1>` type for the conversion it would need to have a concrete `Action<T1>` type to infer `T1` from.

Below a small (silly and impractical) example to show that the problem is not with the inference of `T1` itself, but with the lack of a given concrete `Action<T1>` delegate type from which `T1` could be inferred. Here, just an `Action<double>` delegate is given in the lambda expression, which in turn will allow the compiler to infer `T1`:

```
var sc = new SomeClass();
Action<double> d = sc.MethodB;
builder.AddMethod(x => d);    // Gives no error anymore
```

or, somewhat less silly:

```
builder.AddMethod(x => (Action<double>) x.MethodB);    // Gives no error anymore
```